# How to create VM image of Windows 10 on external drive using KVM?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I'm having quite a hard time to get this through as though it seems simple but I couldn't find well enough solution.

I'm running KVM on Ubuntu (Budgie 18.04)

I'm having an external HDD (80GB) and I'd like to use it to store my virtual images. For now it would be just a single one with Windows 10 installation - but I completely don't know how to force KVM to install actual VM on external drive. Can you help me with this?

I've been trying to create new storage pool - but there's a first problem - should I use "dir: Filesystem Directory" or "disk: Physical Disk Device" or maybe something else? After trying both none of these work - the "disk" option actually managed to boot installation of Windows 10 but it didn't see any drive to chose. The former option didn't let me create storage volume with ".raw" - stating that the operation is not permitted. I'm not actually sure what does any of it mean. I've never have tried any of this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you need to know is the disk for a VM is stored as a file. There is no way it will occupy the whole disk, so it really doesn't matter whether you are storing it in an internal or external HDD. All you need is the free space to create the 'disk' file.

I would assume that you're using Desktop Environment. First, you need to mount the external HDD. You can do it via Disk Utility if you haven't done it.

Then, check out this article:
https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.linuxtechi.com/install-configure-kvm-ubuntu-18-04-server/amp/

Follow Step 2 and make sure you have installed everything mentioned. Probably you have already installed most of it, just double check if virt-manager has been installed as well.

If you can get to Step 5, then you simply need to create the disk on the external HDD mount point and continue to finish it.

Comment: But where do I specify the actual path to the external HDD? After going through the Step 5 If i am not mistaken it creates VM on my internal SSD without asking about where to put it before. No need to create storage pool and storage volume? I'm just so green about it.

Comment: @ThatKidMike you should tick "Customize Configuration Before Install" then follow this instruction to finish the HDD setup. https://www.google.com/amp/s/ckirbach.wordpress.com/2017/07/25/how-to-add-a-physical-device-or-physical-partition-as-virtual-hard-disk-under-virt-manager/amp/

Comment: Thank you for the help. Combining what you posted earlier with this link from your comment I've managed to install VM on my external disc.